# how do i compare greater than or equal to 1 min of given timestamp

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a table in sql server and mysql and my application inserts the records to sqlserver first and then the records get inserted in to the mysql table.

I need to compare a particular record from mysql to sqlserver with the lastupdated time in the where condition. I need to compare like given below

```
select *
  from sqltable
  where sqlupdatedtimestamp > DATEADD(SECOND, 60, MYSQLUPDATETIMESTAMP );
```

I need to bring the records which has inserted within 0 to 60 seonds interval inbetween both the tables?

Comment: Instead of DATEADD you should look at DATEDIFF.

Comment: how do i check if the time difference between tow dates are between 0 to 60 seconds? can you throw some example?

Comment: What's wrong with the query you're using?

Comment: Did you even look at the documentation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using DATEDIFF it would be something along these lines. Please note, this will get any rows where those two datetimes are within a minute of each. You may need to adjust this depending on your specific requirements.

```
where DATEDIFF(second, sqlupdatedtimestamp, MYSQLUPDATETIMESTAMP) > -60
AND DATEDIFF(second, sqlupdatedtimestamp, MYSQLUPDATETIMESTAMP) < 60
```

Answer (score 0):

another option:

```
select *
from sqltable
where sqlupdatedtimestamp between 
    DATEADD(second, -60, MYSQLUPDATETIMESTAMP )
    AND DATEADD(second, 60, MYSQLUPDATETIMESTAMP )
```